# Bind a TextBlock in DataGrid to a global variable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How to bind a TextBlock in DataGrid to a global variable
Below you ll find my global variable

```
 public static string Combox = "Model Dimension";

 public string DataText { get { return Combox; } }
```

Here is my datagrid textBlock

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Combox}" />
      </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

when i tried my code i have an empty TextBlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind using `x:Static` like this -

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static namespace:ClassName.Combox}}"/>
```

You need to define namespace at root level (may be at Window) or at TextBlock level like this -

```
<TextBlock xmlns:my="clr-namespace:EMWParameters;assembly=assemblyName"
           Text="{Binding Source={x:Static my:MainWindow.Combox}}"/>
```

Comment: my namespace is EMWParameters and my class is MainWindow so when i put EMWParameters.MainWindow.Combox i get an error : Type 'EMWParameters.MainWindow' was not found.

Comment: i get this error Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'EMWParameters' that is not included in the assembly.

Comment: Is your class `MainWindow` in different assembly? If yes you need to pass assembly name as well in URI. Check an update in answer.

Comment: It seems some issue in your approach because this works with small sample.

Comment: could i sent to my example

Answer (score 0):

For binding you need to have a property:

```
 public static string Combox{get;set;}

 static ClassName()
 {
      Combox = "Model Dimension";
 }
```